# Haskell - List manipulation

Tags: list, haskell

How would I do the following in Haskell?

```
INPUT: lst = [[("car", 40)],[("truck", 60)],[("motocycle", 50)],[("jeep", 60)]]

OUTPUT: newlst = [("car", 40),("truck", 60),("motocycle", 50),("jeep", 60)]
```

I basically want to be able to convert the `INPUT` list to the `OUTPUT` list. One thing that came to mind was flattening the list but I just can't seem to rap my mind around it.

Comment: Use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to search for the type signature you need. `concat` is the first result when you [search for `[[a]]->[a]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[[a]]-%3E[a]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aconcat).

```
> concat [[("car", 40)],[("truck", 60)],[("motocycle", 50)],[("jeep", 60)]]
[("car",40),("truck",60),("motocycle",50),("jeep",60)]
```